# Calculating grade averages

Tags: statistics

Dear mathstackexchange, 
  There is one module at college that im worried about, can you help me calculate what I need to pass? The homeworks are worth $20\%$ and I got $8\%$.  The final is worth $80\%$.  The paper is out of $400$ marks.  If I need $40\%$ in the module overall to continue to next year, how many marks must I get out of $400$ ? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify where you got 8% out of 20% for the homework i.e. you got 40% of the homework correct or if you only got 8% of all the homework correct. This affects the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want to calculate
$$
0.4 = 0.2 \cdot 0.08 + 0.8x \iff x = \frac{0.4-0.2 \cdot 0.08}{0.8} = 0.48.
$$
The amount of points you need for the exam is then $0.48\cdot 400 = 192$.

Good luck!

Comment: Please state your assumptions. You have interpreted the 8% in one of two possible ways.

Comment: I assumed he got a grade of 8% for a piece of work that determines 20% of the end result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you scored $40\%$ of the homework correctly: If you scored $8\%$ in the homework worth $20\%$, then you will need to score $32\%$ in your $80$% final. $\frac{32\%}{80\%} \,\times 400=160 $ marks needed.

Comment: Please state your assumptions. You have interpreted the 8% in one of two possible ways.

Comment: @IanMiller Thanks, edited!